# reconstructing time-stretched signals for filtering purposes

Tags: matlab, filters, python

I would like to know if it's possible to reconstruct the original time domain signal from it's time-stretched version? Is there any algorithm out there that can do this? Python, Matlab, etc?

I want to isolate certain sound events in the signal, however, the events are really close together, that it's hard to filter. A solution that I had in mind was to stretch the signal, filter this time-stretched signal and then reconstruct back by back stretching using inverse stretching factor to get the original length.

The algorithm will of course have to keep the correct pitch at all times. Is this possible or not?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a good approach at all. In fact, I think the idea is so far off that it's probably not even worth discussing. However, if you shared a better description of your original problem and you would almost certainly receive helpful suggestions for a practical solution.

Comment: I am aware that is perhaps not a best approach, however my question is just to see if that is possible, not here to discuss about the best method.

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a better answer. If you insist on an answer, mine is "no".

Comment: fake doppler.  stretch or pitch but not both

Comment: What sort of "sound events" are you trying to isolate?

Comment: I was thinking about a scenario where overlapping short transients interfere with the human speech. Most algorithms consider speech to be transient in itself, so I was thinking if I can stretch it, the speech becomes less transient for the algorithm, while the overlapping transient is so short in duration, that it will be still considered as a transient by the algorithm, so I can then separate it from the speech. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your “correct pitch” after a time stretch can become a more difficult problem than your original problem of filtering short events.  Both require a time-frequency resolution trade-off.